# Grails : "No domain class found for name project.Smthg" Again, but No Solution for me

Tags: grails, java

I got the following error when trying to "generate-all" in *STS* :

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Packaging Grails application.
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Domain class not found in grails-app/domain, trying hibernate mapped classes...
| Packaging Grails application.
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Packaging Grails application.
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| No domain class found for name project.Smthg. Please try again and enter a valid domain class name
```

Now, my project is called "Project". I'm using *Grails 2.2.1* and *JDK1.7*.

The first time I done a "generate-all" it worked, but since I deleted my generated .groovy files, I can't do it anymore, even with "clean" and "refresh dependencies". 
I tried to reinstall *STS*, Groovy, I created a new workspace and deleted the .groovy and .grails directory in my *HOME*.

I don't know what to do, even with this fresh configuration I can't get it working...

In advance, thanks for helping me !

Comment: Please mention with fresh configuration, what error message you got? or getting the same?

Comment: When I said a fresh configurqtion, I meant all composants reinstalled : STS / Grails and all .* directories deleted.
The error is still the same again and again...

Comment: All right, I think I just solved the problem. Does anyone can confirm that for this command (generate-all) we need to have the concerned groovy file (here Smthg.groovy) already in the "domain" folder ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading your comment...

> All right, I think I just solved the problem. Does anyone can confirm
>   that for this command (generate-all) we need to have the concerned
>   groovy file (here Smthg.groovy) already in the "domain" folder ? Thank
>   you.

...it looks like you are confused about what the `generate-all` command does.  The [manual](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Command%20Line/generate-all.html) tells us that the `generate-all` command:

> Generates a controller, views, and a controller unit test for the
>   given domain class

The phrase of note here is `for the given domain class`.  The domain class(es) you are trying to run `generate-all` on must exist before `generate-all` can work.

Comment: I agree on your point, its better to refer what exactly `generate-all` command does, in [manual](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Command%20Line/generate-all.html)